# Loading resources in android with best performance

Tags: android, string, resources, loading

from time to time I make little tests to get an idea what costs performance in Android.
Todays code:

```
final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                String s = getString(R.string.t1) + " " + getString(R.string.t2) + " " + getString(R.string.t3);
                String s = String.format(getString(R.string.str_format), getString(R.string.t4));
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate " + "diff: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " ms");
        }
    }).run();
```

The resources I used:

```
<string name="t1">Hello</string>
<string name="t2">little</string>
<string name="t3">bird</string>
<string name="str_format">Hello %1$s</string>
<string name="t4">little bird</string>
```

Logcat says (10k iterations):

1. run (chaining every string by its own): ~270ms
2. run (using String.format): ~200ms

So in this example it's 30-40% faster to using the String.format().

My question: is this the best possible way to load String resources or are there any other opportunities?

Comment: This has little or nothing to do with string resources. It has everything to do with [string concatenation in Java](http://java67.blogspot.com/2015/05/4-ways-to-concatenate-strings-in-java.html). You would get similar results if you replaced `getString()` calls with references to regular strings. "are there any other opportunities?" -- Java programmers use `StringBuilder` to concatenate strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're doing is the only way. If you're just doing this for personal interest, there might be more variance when using strings from arrays.xml or plurals.

There is also a built in string format `getString(R.string.str_format, getString(R.string.t4))` I don't know how this compares to `String.format`